# Better bounds for exact-intersection Erdős–Ko–Rado system?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

> What is the largest possible number of subsets of a $4n$-element set $X$, such that each subset contains precisely $2n$ elements, and such that each of the pairwise intersections of the subsets has precisely $n$ elements?

The best bounds I have for the maximal size $N$ of such a set system are $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor \le N \le 8n-1$ (*corrected: was $2n-1$*).  The lower bound is by a tree-like construction based on the characteristic vectors of the subsets relative to $X$, while the upper bound comes from the [Plotkin bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotkin_bound) applied to the Hamming distances between these vectors.  Are better bounds known?

The usual [Erdős–Ko–Rado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem) setup involves the size of the intersections being of *at least* some size, whereas here they are *precisely* $n$.  The EKR upper bounds are exponential in $n$ as they allow many possible set systems where the intersections have different sizes, while a *linear* upper bound appears to be available for this case.  So this seems like it should be a well known example, and I would appreciate a pointer if this is the case.

This is a reformulation of a question from Math.SE, [Number of binary strings of length $n$ with Hamming distance $n/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433584/number-of-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-hamming-distance-n-2), based on my answer to that question.  I am interested in such set systems for general values; the $4n/2n/n$ case avoids some of the distracting details.

---

*Edit:* upon investigation of the history of the Frankl-Wilson theorem, it seems that a better upper bound is due to Ryser: $N \le 4n$.  This applies as long as the common size of intersections is at least 2 and less than the size of the subsets.  Thanks go to Joshua Erde, Gerry Myerson and Ben Millwood for suggesting Frankl-Wilson for the upper bound.

- H. J. Ryser, *An Extension of a Theorem of de Bruijn and Erdös on Combinatorial Designs*, Journal of Algebra **10** 246–261, 1968.  doi:[10.1016/0021-8693(68)90099-9](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693%2868%2990099-9)

Thanks also to Benoît Kloeckner for pointing out a rescaling error.
Benoît also pointed out that a better lower bound of $4n-1$ exists if $n$ is a power of 2, by [Sylvester's construction of Hadamard matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Sylvester.27s_constructiona), and that the existence of Hadamard matrices of every multiple of 4 (which is the Hadamard conjecture) would imply a general lower bound of $4n-1$.

So, assuming the Hadamard conjecture, $4n-1 \le N \le 4n$.  If the conjecture is false, the maximum number of rows of a Hadamard-like matrix with $4n$ columns provides a lower bound for $N$.

It is interesting that there remains a gap between lower and upper bounds, even assuming the Hadamard conjecture.
A set system with $N=4n$ would correspond to a Hadamard-like matrix with $4n$ columns and $4n+1$ rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your upper bound seems wrong to me.

Let first $n=1$, $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $A_i=\{1,i\}$ for $i=2,3,4$. Then we have $3>2\cdot 1-1$ subsets of size $2$ intersecting each other in $1$ point.

More generally, for any integer $k>1$ Sylvester constructed a Hadamard matrix of order $2^k$, that is a matrix with $1$ and $-1$ as coefficient, such that all rows are pairwise orthogonal. One can take the first row to be all $1$ and let $n=2^{k-2}$, so that all subsequent rows have $2n$ positive coefficients, and two of them must share exactly $n$ coefficient. Letting you subset be defined by positive coefficients of the rows of such a matrix gives you an example of size $4n-1$.

Moreover, it is conjectured that Hadamard matrices exist in all dimension multiple of $4$, which would mean that $N\geq 4n-1$. Sylvester construction already shows that this holds for powers of $2$.

Answer (score 3):

The Frankl-Wilson theorem gives you some bounds in this sort of set up:

Let $p$ be a prime. $\mathcal{A} \subset [n]^{(r)}$ such that for all $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$, $|A \cap B| \equiv \lambda_i$ mod $p$ for some $\{\lambda_1 , \ldots \lambda_s\}$ where $\lambda_i \neq r$ mod $p$. Then $|\mathcal{A}| \leq {n \choose s}$.

A quick consequence of this theorem is the Ray-Chaudhury-Wilson theorem, that is let $\mathcal{A} \subset [n]^{(r)}$ such that for all $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$, $|A \cap B| \in L$ for some $L \subset \{0,1,\ldots,r-1\}$, with $|L|=s$. Then $|\mathcal{A}| \leq {n \choose s}$, which can be seem by picking some $p > r$ and applying the previous theorem.

Unfortunately this gives a worse bound than your current upper bound when we take $n=4m$, $r=2m$ and $L=\{m\}$, but possibly it's of more use in the general case.

Comment: Actually, Frankl-Wilson with $p > n$ and $s=1$ gives an upper bound of $n$.

Comment: Possibly there was a confusion of notation. We do get an upper bound of $n=4m$, however this was worse than the claimed upper bound of $2m$ (but I see this has now changed).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that for every $n$ there is an upper bound of $N \le 4n-1$. Let $X = \{1,2,\ldots, 4n\}$. One can associate for each subset $A\subseteq X$ a vector $v_A \in \{-1,1\}^{4n}$ as follows: $v_A(i) = 1$ iff $i \in A$. 
Consider a family of subsets, where each subset is of size $2n$, and the size of the intersection of each two subsets is exactly $n$. This implies that the vectors associated with the subsets are orthogonal over the reals. In addition, these vectors are also orthogonal to the vector $1^{4n}$, hence there are at most $4n-1$ such vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof that $|X| \leq 4n-1$. Given your system $X$, let $\chi_1 , \ldots, \chi_N \in \mathbb{R}^{4n}$ be the characteristic vectors of the elements of $X$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
\chi_i \cdot \chi_k = 
\begin{cases} 2n & i = k
\\
n & i \neq k .
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Let $j \in \mathbb{R}^{4n}$ denote the all ones vector and consider the vectors $$(2 \chi_1 - j) , \ldots , (2 \chi_N - j), j.$$ These are vectors with $\pm 1$ entries and an easy calculation reveals they are pairwise orthogonal. Thus these are $N+1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{4n}$ that are linearly independent so $N+1 \leq 4n$.

The tensor product of two Hadamard matrices is again a Hadamard matrix. As mentioned before, one can construct a Hadamard matrix for all powers of 2 by taking the tensor product of $$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right)$$

Many constuctions of Hadamard matrices are [known](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2086&context=infopapers) and they are known to exist if $4n < 668$ and it is an important conjecture in combinatorics that they exist for all values of $4n$. One easy construction I will mention here is take $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and define the $p \times p$ matrix, $Q$, as follows $$Q_{ij} =  \left(\frac{i-j}{p}\right).$$ Then $$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & j^T \\
j & Q - I
\end{array}\right),$$ is a Hadamard matrix.